# Why did I get the Suffrage badge while voting only 28 times today?

Tags: bug

Just now, I encountered this:

[image: What?!?!?!]

What on this world did just go on - I voted 28 times today on meta and got a badge for 30 votes in a day, for Suffrage. I tried to click on the "select badge to track" and it showed me the same. **How come this happened?**

Note: Vox populi isn't the badge I'm after, I just changed it so to make a screenshot.

Comment: Perhaps the thing that displays the number of votes you made is out of sync with the thing that counts the votes and awards the badge.

Comment: When you say you voted 28 times in a day, do you mean in your day, or in an SE day (which is in UTC)? That might explain it.

Comment: @Ash Since I'm in UTC+1, the difference doesn't really affect me. So it's in a SE day.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a syncing issue.  Look again in an hour.  I've seen the same with other badges.

Comment: Maybe speculating, but after getting the first badge, 2 of your votes could be on removed content. I think this will roll back progress on the other badge.

Comment: @camelCase this was around for a hour or so; I decided to post it here. I voted two or three times just now, and it shows Vox Populi: 32/40. And also, it tells me "max vote limit reached". Getting crazy now, I guess :)

Comment: Check your votes, and see if anything was deleted.  I think you can do that through your profile.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/143228/rudolf-l-jelínek?tab=votes

Comment: @camelCase Thanks for the link, but I had already checked that. No posts were deleted that I voted on, since I almost never vote on post that will be deleted (why do it?) except if they deserve an upvote. Checked anyways.

Comment: Okay, worth a shot.  Did you check the count too?